# how to plot only True signal with plotly candlestick chart

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-python, candlestick-chart

Here is the code I am using:

```
df['C'] = np.where((df['spread'] > 60) & (df['volume'] > df['Ma_mult_high']),'green','red')

fig = go.Figure()


# add OHLC trace
fig.add_trace(go.Candlestick(x=df.index,
                            open=df['open'],
                            high=df['high'],
                            low=df['low'],
                            close=df['close'], 
                            showlegend=False))
# add moving average traces
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index, 
                        y=df['ma'], 
                        opacity=0.7, 
                        line=dict(color='blue', width=2), 
                        name='MA 5'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x = df.index,
    y = df['close'],
    mode = 'markers',
    marker_color=df.C

))
fig.update_layout(xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False).show()`
```

the output

[image]

in the image, you can see that plot both True and false signal, maybe because the `marker_color = "C"` but if change that and use only color names it will plot noting even if i change the `y = df['close']`, i get the same problem

data `{'timeStamp': {0: 1657220400000, 1: 1657222200000, 2: 1657224000000, 3: 1657225800000, 4: 1657227600000}, 'open': {0: 21357.7, 1: 21495.84, 2: 21812.46, 3: 21641.56, 4: 21624.03}, 'high': {0: 21499.87, 1: 21837.74, 2: 21838.1, 3: 21659.99, 4: 21727.87}, 'low': {0: 21325.0, 1: 21439.13, 2: 21526.4, 3: 21541.96, 4: 21567.56}, 'close': {0: 21495.83, 1: 21812.47, 2: 21641.56, 3: 21624.03, 4: 21619.57}, 'volume': {0: 3663.2089, 1: 7199.91652, 2: 4367.94336, 3: 1841.10043, 4: 1786.17022}, 'quoteVolume': {0: 78386481.2224664, 1: 155885063.7202956, 2: 94605455.6190078, 3: 39756576.8814698, 4: 38684342.7232105}, 'tradesCount': {0: 59053, 1: 111142, 2: 81136, 3: 56148, 4: 53122}, 'date': {0: Timestamp('2022-07-07 19:00:00'), 1: Timestamp('2022-07-07 19:30:00'), 2: Timestamp('2022-07-07 20:00:00'), 3: Timestamp('2022-07-07 20:30:00'), 4: Timestamp('2022-07-07 21:00:00')}, 'Avg_Volume': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan}, 'Ma_mult_high': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan}, 'Ma_mult_mid': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan}, 'spread': {0: 78.9901069365825, 1: 79.43353152203923, 2: 54.82836060314386, 3: 14.85215623146836, 4: 2.782109662528346}, 'Marker': {0: 21502.87, 1: 21840.74, 2: 21523.4, 3: 21538.96, 4: 21564.56}, 'Symbol': {0: 'triangle-up', 1: 'triangle-up', 2: 'triangle-down', 3: 'triangle-down', 4: 'triangle-down'}, 'ma': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0}, 'C': {0: 'red', 1: 'red', 2: 'red', 3: 'red', 4: 'red'}}`

Comment: can you include a sample of your data so we can reproduce your plot? you can copy and paste the output from `df.head().to_dict()` into your question– thanks!

Comment: @DerekO of course

Comment: I used the data provided to check the issues, but was not sure what the issues were. Is the issue that the colors set in the column settings do not match the colors of the markers? All provided were red, so I could not confirm the issue.

Comment: @r-beginners no the issue in plotting it plot false and true signa above the candle I only want to plot the true signal above the candle

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the issue is in your `np.where()` statement, likely with the `nan` values in Ma_multi_high producing the false statement in `df['volume'] > df['Ma_mult_high']` that result in 'red'.

Try this:

```
df['C'] = np.where((df['spread'] > 60) & (df['volume'] > df['Ma_mult_high'].fillna(0)),'green','red')
```

Comment: thinks for tring to help me but still the same i think it because  marker_color  i used np.where sof if the condition true it will plot green dot and if it false it will be red dot

Comment: I get that the colors are wrong, but it's probably still because of the `np.where()` statement rather than an issue with Plotly. Could you please run `df[['spread', 'volume', 'Ma_mult_high', 'C']]` to see if the criteria within 'spread', 'volume', and 'Ma_mult_high' is producing the desired color in 'C'?

Comment: i just replace np.where with np.select and know it work fine, and again thinks for tring to help me

Comment: @mtfr8_me if you have a solution it might help some future person if you submit that as an answer and mark this solved.